# Equelheight.js loading issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Equelheight.js to make blocks on my site same height but now when the page load it the blocks is the same height but the writing in my block goes over the blocks. The writing get loaded from the database. The issue is that the content gets loaded after jquery function. I hope this make sense at all.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".article-block").equalHeight();
});
```

CSS

```
.article-block
{
background-color: #fff;
text-align: left;
padding: 21px 21px;
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="article-block  shadow" style="position: relative">
    <div class="pin pin-@colour"></div>
    <div>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")"><img class="article-image img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" /></a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="article-heading">
        <a class="article-heading" href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")">@item.Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="article-date">
        @item.DateCreated
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="article-intro">
        @item.Introduction
    </div>
    <div class="read-more bottom">
        <a class="read-more" href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution I just added a delay for jquery function to kick off:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".article-block").equalHeight();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a fiddle?
Anyway, try to add this CSS:

```
.article-block div{overflow:auto;}
```

But it will show scrollbar on the div.

Or, you could call the jQuery .equalHeight(); after the content loaded. Call $(".article-block").equalHeight(); last. Like this;

```
<body>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-block  shadow" style="position: relative">
      <div class="pin pin-@colour"></div>
      <div>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")"><img class="article-image img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" /></a>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="article-heading">
        <a class="article-heading" href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")">@item.Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="article-date">
        @item.DateCreated
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="article-intro">
        @item.Introduction
      </div>
      <div class="read-more bottom">
        <a class="read-more" href="@Url.Action("Article","Home")">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".article-block").equalHeight();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Let me know if it works.